# Swap table cell color on click

Tags: javascript, css

I want to be able to click a table cell, have it switch to color1, and then on the next click have it switch to color2, then back to color1... and so on.

```
function cSwap(cell){ 
 if (cell.style.backgroundColor = "#00000F")
 {
  cell.style.backgroundColor = "#F00000";
 }
 else if (cell.style.backgroundColor = "#F00000")
 {
  cell.style.backgroundColor = "#00000F";
 }
}
```

Right now, it only changes to the first color, and subsequent clicks do nothing.

The cells of the table each look like this:

```
<td classname='t' onclick='cSwap(this);' width='100' height='100' id='nw'><a href="" id="nw"></a></td>
```

...which'll be CSS once I get everything working (beside the point).

Comment: Sorry, they're actually different. I just happened to grab that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with double equal signs it won't work. `backgroundColor` will change its string to an `rgb` value in Firefox when its value is retrieved (and other browsers may behave alike).

A solution is to put those colors in a class and switch the table cell's class on click. That's also more general, as you can easily change the colors.

CSS:

```
.t  { background: #00f }
.t2 { background: #f00 }
```

Also, the *attribute* is called `class`, not `classname`. And remember that you cannot have two elements with the same ID:

```
<td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)' width='100' height='100'><a href=""></a></td>
<td class='t' onclick='cSwap(this)' width='100' height='100'><a href=""></a></td>
```

And the accompanying script:

```
function cSwap(cell){  
    if (cell.className == "t")
        cell.className = "t2";
    else if (cell.className == "t2")
        cell.className = "t";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need double equals for comparison:

```
  if (cell.style.backgroundColor == "#00000F")
```

or [triple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs) equals if you prefer.